# MVC Custom constructor never hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am using Autofac for IoC, in my controllers folder contains 2 controller,

```
class PokemonController : ApiController
```

and

```
class HomeController : Controller.
```

I'm pretty sure I have the IoC setup correctly since the `PokemonController` access the interface `IPokemonRepositoryService` just fine, but with the `HomeController` my custom constructor was never hit. Only the default parameterless ctor was hit.

```
    private readonly IPokemonRepositoryService _pokemonRepositoryService;

    public HomeController()
    {

    }

    public HomeController(IPokemonRepositoryService pokemonRepositoryService)
    {
        _pokemonRepositoryService = pokemonRepositoryService;
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out what might be the cause and how I can fix it?

**Exception stack trace**

> Server Error in '/' Application. No parameterless constructor defined
>   for this object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for this object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +122
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +239    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'Pokemon.WebAPI.Controllers.HomeController'. Make
>   sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +188    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +444    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

**Edit:**
Adding AutofacConfig

```
public class AutofacConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var bldr = new ContainerBuilder();
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            bldr.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HomeController)));
            bldr.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PokemonController)));
            RegisterServices(bldr);
            bldr.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
            bldr.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();
            var container = bldr.Build();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder bldr)
        {
            bldr.RegisterType<PokemonContext>()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            bldr.RegisterType<PokemonRepositoryService>()
                .As<IPokemonRepositoryService>()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            bldr.RegisterType<LevenshteinService>()
                .As<ILevenshteinService>()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            bldr.RegisterType<PokemonParseService>()
                .As<IPokemonParseService>()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new PokemonMapping());
            });

            bldr.RegisterInstance(config.CreateMapper())
                .As<IMapper>()
                .SingleInstance();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the default constructor ` HomeController()`

Comment: I had no default ctor at the beginning, but it returns an MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined

Comment: have you got this registered in any of your startup files?

Comment: couldn't you provide the exception stack trace pls?

Comment: @SimonPrice What kind of registration do I need to do? I'm not aware of it

Comment: @Wladyslaw I have included the exception stack trace

Comment: take a look at this and this should hopefully help you, but typically depends on which DI methods \ provider your using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Honestly, seems like your IoC setup still not correct. Are you using .net core? If so check that you populated the .NET Core DI services with Autofac by calling the `builder.Populate()` and you have called `services.AddControllersWithViews()` as well. It also would usefull to see how you're registering the types.

Comment: Could you share how you register types ? are you using Autofac ? how is it configured ? Seems strange that `PokemonController` works but not `HomeController` could you share this constructor as well ? are you sure that this controller is working fine ?

Comment: @Wladyslaw I have added my AutofacConfig, can you take a look?

Comment: @CyrilDurand can it be because I'm only setting up the ApiController correctly but not the regular controller?